# Set retry with delay to a failed Sqs message that was executed by a lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, dlq

I have a lambda function that is triggered by an SQS message.
I want to set a retry for the message incase of failure.
The thing is, i want this retry to be executed after 5 minutes delay.
How can i do that? I'm currently not using a DLQ, but can add one if necessary.
The thing is I'm not sure DLQ supports delay messages.
I know there's the delayMessage param for SQS, but for my understanding it is set once when putting the message in the queue. And for the original execution i don't want the delay - Only for the retry.
Suggestions?

Pssoible solutions i don't want to use-

- sleep within the lambda before raising
- Not sending the same message again to the queue, but a new message with the delayMessage parameter

Comment: SQS has no automatic way of doing this for you. "Not sending the same message again to the queue, but a new message with the delayMessage parameter" You may not want to use that method, but it is your best option.